# Возможна ли настройка COM-порта с помощью своего приложения

Tags: python, tkinter, serial, pyserial

Возможно ли в принципе с PySerial использовать порт не с заранее заданными настройками (порт, битрейт, стопбиты, и прочее), а задавать их с помощью, например, комбобоксов из tkinter? И если это возможно, то можно ли, пожалуйста, пример как это делается?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676172/full-examples-of-using-pyserial-package

Comment: Эту ветку я видел, но там ведь параметры задаются сразу в коде, не настраиваются в приложении. Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Так это переменные изменяй как хочешь

Comment: Окей, порт и битрейт видно, что просто переменные, но стопбиты, биты и четность? Они ведь вроде как по-особому там записываются, например, не 8, а EIGHTBITS, не просто None, а PARITY_NONE, как в это дело преобразовывать данные из комбобоксов?